# regarding converting sql to hql

Tags: hibernate

how to select column's value as null in hql?

ex: In sql

```
 select null as empname from emp; in sql

   In hql
```

ex: select emp.empname as col1 from Employee emp;

I want to select empname' value as null as explained in the above sql query

An

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast function. Like this,

```
select cast(null as char) as hede from emp e
```

Or use quotes and change your controls to empty checks.

```
select '' as hede from emp e
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply i need it in hql

Comment: sreelatha you can use cast in your hql. Like select cast(null as char) as col1, emp.otherColumn ... from Employee emp;

Comment: i tried as mentioned below it s giving org.hibernate.QueryException select cast(null as char) as emp.col1, emp.otherColumn ... from Employee emp; can you please tell me whats wrong ....?

Comment: you are trying to get the casted value as 'emp.col1'. That is the case. Only a column name can be here.

Comment: ok thank you.i forgot to tell                                  select cast(null as char) as D_LOC,e.empname from (select d.location,e.empno from Employee e,Dept d where d.empno=e.empno and e.empno='1');can you please tell   Is this correct?

Comment: i don't think select from select possible in hql.